# override page.tpl.php for the login page in Drupal 7

Tags: authentication, drupal-7, overriding

I want to override the page.tpl.php to make a custom login page.
The class of the body tag of the actual login is:

```
<body class="html front not-logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-first page-customerror page-customerror- page-customerror-403 i18n-en">
```

how could be the name of the new file to override the page.tpl.php?

I have tried `page--not-logged-in.tpl.php`, `page-not-logged-in.tpl`, `page-front-not-logged-in.tpl` but nothing seems to work.

I also flush the cache every time I change the name of the file but nothings happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a preprocess function

1) Add in your `template.php`

```
function yourcustomtheme_preprocess_page($vars) {
   global $user;
   if ($user->uid ==0)) {
      $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-not-logged';
   }
}
```

2) Now, you can use `page-not-logged.tpl.php`

Other way, you can use the same template for all users

Edit your `page.tpl.php` and add

```
<?php 
 global $user;
 if($user->uid ==0 ){
   //Your code for anon users
 }
 else {
  //Copy the original page.tpl here
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's `template.php` file

```
function [YOUR_THEME]_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    global $user;

    if($user->uid < 1 && arg(0) == "user") {
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'page-not-logged-in';
    }
}
```